# Reverse for 'user-profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am making a simple django site where users can click on other users to view their comments (by clicking their profile). However django keeps throwing this error when I run the site.

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),


    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
    path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name='user-profile'),

    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
    path('update-room/<str:pk>', views.updateRoom, name="update-room"),
    path('delete-room/<str:pk>', views.deleteRoom, name="delete-room"),
    path('delete-message/<str:pk>', views.deleteMessage, name="delete-message"),
```

my template page 1(profile.html)

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}
<h1>{{user.username}}</h1>



{% endblock content %}
```

feed_component.html (feed component on my home page)

```
<div>
    {% for room in rooms %}
        <div>
            {% if request.user == room.host%}
            <a href="{% url 'update-room' room.id%}">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete-room' room.id %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}

            <a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}">@{{room.host.username}}</a>
            <h5>{{room.id}} -- <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{room.name}}</a></h5>
            <small>{{room.topic.name}}</small>
            <hr>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py

```
def loginPage(request):

    page = 'login'

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try: 
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username or password does not match')


    context = {'page': page}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


def registerPage(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'An error occured during registration')

    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', {'form': form})



def home(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''

    rooms = Room.objects.filter(
        Q(topic__name__icontains=q) |
        Q(name__icontains=q) |
        Q(description__icontains=q)
        )
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    room_count = rooms.count()
    room_messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(room__topic__name__icontains=q))


    context = {'rooms': rooms, 'topics' : topics, 'room_count': room_count, 'room_messages':room_messages}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)

def room(request,pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = room.message_set.all()
    participants = room.participants.all()

    if request.method=='POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            room=room,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        room.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('room', pk=room.id)

    context = {'room': room,'room_messages': room_messages, 'participants': participants}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)



def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    context = {'user': user, 'rooms' : rooms}
    return render(request, 'base/profile.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of forgetting a simple space, of course, I encountered this error just today and two hours later I realized that my problem is a simple space... space between equal sign and variable....

```
{% if room.host.username == request.user.username %}
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'update-room' room.id %}">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'delete-room' room.id %}">Delete</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `pk` is of `int` type not <s>`str`</s> type.

Simply change your all routes to `<int:pk>/`.

Try below code:

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),


    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('room/<int:pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.userProfile, name='user-profile'),

    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
    path('update-room/<int:pk>/', views.updateRoom, name="update-room"),
    path('delete-room/<int:pk>/', views.deleteRoom, name="delete-room"),
    path('delete-message/<int:pk>/', views.deleteMessage, name="delete-message"),
```

> `Note:` Always give `/` at the end of every route in path function.

> `Note:` Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` not `camelCase`, so it will better if you change your view name to `user_profile` instead of <s>`userProfile`</s>.

Comment: I think i would prefer it to be str because I am matching the names of username, room, topics, etc for some reason it throws errors when I use int. Django says that my feed_component html is the reason for the error but I cant see why that would be case. Not sure if its looping through my rooms --> host and getting a None value and thats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is happening on this line in feed_component.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}">@{{room.host.username}}</a>
```

`room.host.id` is resolving to a blank string, which is caused by a room object with a null host field.

The `Room` model definition does allow for a null host:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
base.Room.host: (fields.E320) Field specifies on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True argument on the field, or change the on_delete rule.

Comment: when I change it to false it throws me this error.  I also saw on the terminal that there was an indentation issue with my url.py but I redid it and still no change

Comment: @Helpmeplease That's because you can't have `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` without also having `null=True`.  Regardless, changing the model definition won't solve anything, because your database _already_ contains a model object with a null host, which is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: when I take away .host from room.host.id I am able to get my home page back but when I try to click the user my get function doesn't work

Comment: @Helpmeplease "my get function doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: my User.objects.get(id=pk) function doesn't work sorry

Comment: So if I click a user on my homepage I will get the error User matching query does not exist.. so Im guessing I need to specify my host but if I use ".host" django will throw my initial error

Comment: John this was the correct answer thanks.  I had to go into admin and delete the  rooms without a host. That seemed to clear up the error

Answer (score 0):

This problem might have occurred because you deleted a user who was having rooms. since you deleted the user's room which sets the room's host to null
"host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)"

I have just resolved this problem; it seems to be a problem due to your rooms not having any host. that's why it is not able to find the user profile for a particular room. just go to your Django admin and check all your room's hosts, if it is null then set any user to its host problem will be solved.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).